# Convert Java-Based Configuration to Spring XML-based

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, birt

I'm trying to convert Birt application done in java annotation to XML based but 'am having difficulties changing this part to xml

```
@Bean   
public BirtViewResolver birtViewResolver() throws Exception {
    BirtViewResolver bvr = new BirtViewResolver();
    bvr.setBirtEngine(this.engine().getObject());
    bvr.setViewClass(HtmlSingleFormatBirtView.class);
    bvr.setDataSource(this.birtDataServiceConfiguration.dataSource());
    bvr.setReportsDirectory("Reports");
    bvr.setOrder(2);
    return bvr;
}
```

I tried this but couldn't figure out how to set birtEngine, viewClass, and dataSource part

```
<beans:bean id="birtViewResolver" class="org.eclipse.birt.spring.core.BirtViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="birtEngine" value="?" />
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="?" />
        <beans:property name="dataSource" value="?" />
        <beans:property name="reportsDirectory" value="Reports" />
        <beans:property name="order" value="2" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How a friendly suggestion, is better define the infrastructure beans through JavaConfig than XML

Comment: @ManuelJordan I'm using xml it's not because it's better, the application I'm working is already using xml and it is easier for me to change the above javaConfig to xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this

```
bvr.setBirtEngine(this.engine().getObject());
```

I'm going to assume `engine()` is another `@Bean` method which returns a `FactoryBean` object. In XML, you would have it as

```
<bean name="engine" class="com.example.EngineFactoryBean" />
```

For

```
bvr.setViewClass(HtmlSingleFormatBirtView.class);
```

Spring can convert from a fully qualified class name as string value in the XML to a `Class` instance at runtime.

For

```
bvr.setDataSource(this.birtDataServiceConfiguration.dataSource());
```

I'm going to assume `birtDataServiceConfiguration` is a reference to another `@Configuration` class which you've `@Autowired` and `dataSource()` is a `@Bean` method declared in that class.

The resulting XML declaration would be like

```
<!-- Assuming you converted that config to XML as well -->
<import resource="classpath:birtDataServiceConfiguration.xml" /> 
<beans:bean id="birtViewResolver" class="org.eclipse.birt.spring.core.BirtViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="birtEngine" ref="engine" />
    <!-- You would have to give the class' fully qualified name -->
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="com.example.fully.qualified.HtmlSingleFormatBirtView" />
    <!-- Assuming that imported config had a bean declared with the name 'dataSource' -->
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="reportsDirectory" value="Reports" />
    <beans:property name="order" value="2" />
</beans:bean>
```